# libGDX launcher for Android Wear?

Tags: android, libgdx, wear-os, watch, launcher

How do I get my libGDX game on Android Wear?
I created a sample project with the gdx-setup.jar but that creates only an android launcher.

I added

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.type.watch" />
```

to the manifest file and this:

```
dependencies {
   compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.0.+@aar'
   compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.0.+'
   wearApp project(':wearable')
}
```

to build.gradle.

But Android Studio only creates an android app.

How can I launch my libGDX game on Android Wear? The sample android launcher don't work for me.

Comment: I don't think you need the dependencies section. Read [here](http://www.phoneprojects.com/blog/using-libgdx-on-android-wear/)

Comment: No, don't work. I've tried so many ways but it's just an apk for Android not for Android Wear. Even if I add an Android War module and copy the launcher code it cannot Start the libgdx game core class

Answer (score 0):

Create the project with the gdx-setup.jar and then create a new wear module with a blank wear application and try the following build.gradle for the wear module:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.wear"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    configurations { natives }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(":core")
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile fileTree(dir: '../libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile 'com.google.android.support:wearable:1.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:7.5.0'
    compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-android:$gdxVersion"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
}
// needed to add JNI shared libraries to APK when compiling on CLI
tasks.withType(com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageApplication) { pkgTask ->
    pkgTask.jniFolders = new HashSet<File>()
    pkgTask.jniFolders.add(new File(projectDir, 'libs'))
}

// called every time gradle gets executed, takes the native dependencies of
// the natives configuration, and extracts them to the proper libs/ folders
// so they get packed with the APK.
task copyAndroidNatives() {
    file("libs/armeabi/").mkdirs();
    file("libs/armeabi-v7a/").mkdirs();
    file("libs/x86/").mkdirs();

    configurations.natives.files.each { jar ->
        def outputDir = null
        if(jar.name.endsWith("natives-armeabi-v7a.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/armeabi-v7a")
        if(jar.name.endsWith("natives-armeabi.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/armeabi")
        if(jar.name.endsWith("natives-x86.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/x86")
        if(outputDir != null) {
            copy {
                from zipTree(jar)
                into outputDir
                include "*.so"
            }
        }
    }
}
```